# Converting Endianess on a bit field structure (again)

Tags: c, endianness, bit-fields

This question was asked before, but I'm still a bit confused on how to deal with bitfield structures when moving to a platform with the opposite endianness (big to little in this case). So if I have this:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short a :5;
    unsigned short b :1;
    unsigned short c :5;
    unsigned short d :5;
} protocol_type;

typedef union
{
  protocol_type cmd;
  unsigned short word;
}protocol_cmd_type;
```

Is the correct way to deal with this, like this?

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short d :5;
    unsigned short c :5;
    unsigned short b :1;
    unsigned short a :5;
} protocol_type;

typedef union
{
  protocol_type cmd;
  unsigned short word;
}protocol_cmd_type;
```

Or something else?

That's what I did, but it's not giving results I was expecting. However there are other issues with this code, so I'm not sure if the above was actually wrong or not. Hoping to get insight here so I can knock this part off the list.

In fact I need to have the code work on both platforms still, so I'd be wrapping things around #defines, but I didn't want to clutter things here.

Comment: Yes, you are right that you just reverse the order of field declarations as you have shown.

Comment: I don't think there's a guarantee (or perhaps not even a reason to believe) that bit ordering in bitfields follow byte ordering in memory. In other words, just because you jump from a little-endian to a big-endian machine, you can't assume that you should reverse all bit fields. In other words: bitfields are very bad for portability, and to be avoided in code that should be portable.

Comment: As unwind mentions, bitfields are very non-portable. Compilers have a lot of freedom in how they can lay them out.  I think it would be better to move the code away from bitfields altogether if you can.

Comment: @TJD I don't think that's correct. If the data was originally written as bitfields, then the byte order doesn't matter - byte 0 bit 0 will be in the same place on either endianness. However, if they were packed into an `int` or `short` before writing out, then endianness does matter - so the bottom line is we probably need to know more. Also, endianness changes the order of bytes, not bits, so simply reversing the entire list is just flat wrong.

Comment: Bit fields aren't portable. Endianess, alignment, bit order and padding bits are not defined by the standard. Further, bit fields can only be of type int, I believe using any other type is undefined behavior. So... tough luck. You should have used bitwise operators if you wanted portable code.

Comment: @twalberg, I've worked on countless projects using bitfields and cross compiling for embedded targets with various endianness.  While the exact treatment of bitfields is not guaranteed to be portable, as Lundin mentions, in practice the behavior I have seen on every target I've encountered is that you end up with ifdefs for endianness and you simply reverse the declared order of the bitfields.

Comment: @TJD So if i have a 1 bit bitfield followed by a 2 bit bitfield (note both will fit in a single byte), then when I switch endianness, somehow the bitfields are in a different order? I don't think that seems right... If I have enough bitfields that I end up with multiple bytes, then certainly some reordering is necessary, but it won't be as simple as simply reversing the list - it's the bytes that are in a different order, not the bits within the bytes.

Comment: For detailed arguments why bit-fields are completely non-portable, please see [this tantrum](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/10/effective-c-tip-6-creating-a-flags-variable/comment-page-1/#comment-2390) I once posted as comment to an otherwise excellent blog.

Comment: @twalberg, yes that is right.  Logically it has no relation to the traditional definition of endianness, so I understand that it is not intuitive.  But in practice, that's what compilers do.  There are two ways to look at this discussion.  From a purist perspective bit fields are not portable.  From a practical perspective, you may just have a couple of targets of interest, so you just look at what they do in memory and make it work.

Comment: Here's a discussion of the issue: http://mjfrazer.org/mjfrazer/bitfields/

Comment: @TJD I guess I'm thinking more of bitfields as interfaces to hardware registers, ports, etc, in cases where reordering the bitfields within a byte is absolutely the wrong thing to do. In a user-defined struct that's just being used for flags, etc, it doesn't matter so much...

Comment: @TJD That link contains a lot of incorrect assumptions, whoever wrote it had not read the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the following structure is **not** portable in terms of not changing the bit pattern used by the structure in memory from little to big endian or verse vica:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short a :5;
    unsigned short b :1;
    unsigned short c :5;
    unsigned short d :5;
} protocol_type;
```

Proof:

Big endian memory layout:

```
 d4   d3   d2   d1   d0   c4   c3   c2   c1   c0   b0   a4   a3   a2   a1  a0
<-             byte 1                -> <-              byte 0              ->  
MSB                                 LSB MSB                                LSB
[              address 1              ] [               address 0            ]
```

Little endian memory layout:

```
 c1   c0   b0   a4   a3   a2   a1  a0   d4   d3   d2   d1   d0   c4   c3   c2 
<-             byte 0               -> <-              byte 1               ->  
MSB                                LSB MSB                                 LSB
[              address 1             ] [               address 0             ]
```

From this I see no way how to re-order `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` to form the same bit pattern on either little and big endian machines. The reason for this is the fact that the structure's member `c` crosses the byte boundary.

---

The following structure might be made portable:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short e :5;
    unsigned short f :3;
    unsigned short g :3;
    unsigned short h :5;
} protocol_type;
```

To keep the bit pattern in memory when switching endianess just mod it like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short g :3;
    unsigned short h :5;
    unsigned short e :5;
    unsigned short f :3;
} protocol_type;
```

---

A possible solution to the OP's problem would be to mod the structure the following way:

```
typedef struct
{
#if defined(BIGENDIAN)
        unsigned short a :5;
        unsigned short b :1;
        unsigned short c0 :2;
        unsigned short c1 :3;
        unsigned short d :5;
#elif defined(LITTLEENDIAN)
        unsigned short c1 :3;
        unsigned short d :5;
        unsigned short a :5;
        unsigned short b :1;
        unsigned short c0 :2;
#else
#error "endianess not supported"
#endif
} protocol_type;


#define pt_c(pt) (pt.c0 & (pt.c1 << 2))

foo(void)
{
   protocol_type pt;

   ... /* some assignment to pt ... */
   /* to then access the original value of member c use the macro */

   unsigned short c = pt_c(pt);
```

Comment: Since neither bit order nor endianess of bitfields are defined by the standard, how did you manage to come up with this? Also, strictly speaking there may be any number of padding bits and padding bytes anywhere inside a bit field.

Comment: I do agree with you on the missing standards. And surely this could lead to trouble when needing to be portable to many different platforms. The solution I proposed is based on my experince on x86 (VC, gcc) and s390x (gcc) and zOS. @Lundin

Answer (score 2):

I would keep what you had originally but reverse the byte order of `word` before referencing (if needed).

Comment: +1 for being straight forward, as apposed to my own solution... ;-) A typicall case to use a `ntohs()`/`htons()`, sure.

Comment: I should've mentioned ntohs() myself, nice one @alk

Comment: I didn't know about ntohs/ntohl/htons/htonl. That saves me from having my own functions for that. Nice!

Comment: A short is most definitely 16 bits on pretty much every platform. A short would be endianess-dependent on the order of 2 bytes. A long on the other hand, would be endianess-dependent over 4 bytes. Now, what happens when you try to put a short inside a bit-field, which must be of type int? Take a guess, because it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You have more to worry about than endianess issues here.  Be aware that the details of how bitfields are laid out in memory is not defined by the C standard, meaning that two compilers can generate different results, even if they are targeting platforms with the same endianess.  Some may treat the first bitfield listed as the lowest-address bit, and others may treat it as the highest-address bit.

You have two options for resolving this.

The first is with a healthy dose of `#ifdef`:

```
typedef struct
{
#ifdef CPU_IS_BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned short a :5;
    unsigned short b :1;
    unsigned short c :5;
    unsigned short d :5;
#else
    unsigned short d :5;
    unsigned short c :5;
    unsigned short b :1;
    unsigned short a :5;
#endif
} protocol_type;
```

This leads to a messy structure definition, but allows the rest of the code to stay clean.  Since you have fields that cross the byte boundary, you'll have to essentially come up with a new structure definition (possibly by trial and error) for every target architecture/platform.  If you have to support multiple compilers that order bitfields differently for the same platform, then your definition will become even more complex.

The other option is to avoid bitfields altogether and use bitmasks instead:

```
typedef unsigned char protocol_type[2];
#define extract_a(x) ((x[0] & 0xF8) >> 3)
#define extract_b(x) ((x[0] & 0x04) >> 2)
#define extract_c(x) (((x[0] & 0x03) << 3) | ((x[1] & 0xE0) >> 5))
#define extract_d(x) ((x[1] & 0x1F))
```

This requires the use of getter/setter methods, but you avoid most of the portability problems since you're explicitly specifying both the bit and byte orders for everything.

Comment: Bitmasks / bitwise operators are 100% portable to any C compiler for any CPU, so they are indeed the best solution. Bit-fields on the other hand, is one of those royally stupid things in the C standard.